# Trouble inserting into table with table valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I created a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE int_array AS TABLE (n INT NOT NULL)
```

and want to use it to insert several rows in a single procedure into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    Id_SecondTable INT NOT NULL,
    Id_ThirdTable  INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_myTable 
        PRIMARY KEY (Id_SecondTable, Id_ThirdTable),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Id_SecondTable 
        FOREIGN KEY (Id_SecondTable) REFERENCES SecondTable (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Id_ThirdTable 
        FOREIGN KEY (Id_ThirdTable) REFERENCES ThirdTable (Id)
)
```

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
     (@value INT, 
      @array int_array READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTable 
    VALUES (Id_SecondTable, Id_ThirdTable) (@value, SELECT n FROM @array)   
END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement is all kinds of wrong. Presumably you meant something like `INSERT myTable(ID_SecondTable, Id_ThirdTable) SELECT @value, n FROM @array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix a scalar value and select statement in your insert. You need to make the scalar value a column in the select instead. Like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(
@value INT, 
@array int_array readonly 
)
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO myTable 
(
    Id_SecondTable
    , Id_ThirdTable
) 
SELECT @value
    , n 
FROM @array
END
```